# Examples of why a world readable /root directory is bad?

Tags: permissions, security, root

To add weight to a discussion I'm having, I'm trying to find concrete examples of why having the /root directory world readable is bad from a security point of view.

I have found plenty of instances online of people repeating the mantra that it's really not good to give /root say, 755 perms, but with no further evidence.

Could someone please provide a scenario where a system's security can be compromised if this is the case? The less contrived the better - so, for example, how can a freshly installed Centos system suffer if /root has 755 perms?

EDIT - Thanks for the replies, but so far no concrete examples. To put it another way, how could you use the fact that /root is visible to compromise the system? Are there any examples of programs being installed and assuming that /root is not accessible to everyone?

EDIT 2 - I think the consensus so far is that it's not a great security risk, other than someone not checking perms and using the directory as if it were private to root.

Comment: UNIX OSes (AIX, HPUX) don't have a `/root` directory - but use the root directory (ie `/` and `drwxr-xr-x`) for root.

Comment: By `/root` do you mean `/`?

Comment: By /root I mean the directory named 'root' that exists at the root of the filesystem '/', that is used as a home area for the root user on most Linuxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fundamentally I think it comes down to a choice made by the core developers and nothing more than that. Why? Because by default, there should be almost nothing of any value to anyone in `/root`. No one should be logging in as the root user for general stuff.

For example, on FreeBSD everyone can read `/root`. Some files within `/root` can not be read for security reasons but you can still "see" those files are there with `ls` (just can not read them). For example, `.history` is set `-rw-------` but `.login` is `-rw-r--r--`.

FreeBSD has a slightly different approach to security to Linux. Historically FreeBSD has been for servers and while it can be run as a Desktop it really is better (by default) as a server.

Personally, I see nothing wrong with this set up (`/root` can be read).

The `/root` on FreeBSD has almost nothing in it except for configs really. Mail should be forwarded to a real user. No one should be logging in as the root user. The account should only be used for installation of and configuration of software as well as maintenance tasks. Other than a few security sensitive files (like `.history`) there is nothing to hide in `/root` in my opinion, on FreeBSD.

For more reading on this, try the [FreeBSD handbook section on security](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/security.html). I did not see anything on their choice to make `/root` readable in a quick scan but there is a lot info there.

Comment: OpenBSD chooses to have `/root` chmod 700 (not accessible by anyone except root), but it's the same here, root's files and directories are usually not touched or changed anyway (there's no real reason to).

Answer (score 2):

This is not fundamentally any different than the recommendation to prevent other users from reading any other user's home directory.

If the default is world readable, there will be a window of opportunity when you are saving a new file which you intend to keep private.  There is always a chance that somebody could copy it before you can `chmod go-r` it.

Comment: I challenge why the /root directory is needed in the first place. /root is the home directory of the root user, but it would be better for security not to log in as root at all, and in fact disable the root account altogether. Use sudo instead.

Comment: That would also work, but doesn't answer the OP's question, and might not be a realistic option in many organizations.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a careless admin searches for easily-cracked passwords and leaves the output lying around (this may not be the correct invocation, but you get the idea):

```
# john-the-ripper /etc/shadow > ~/cracked-passwords.txt
```

Comment: This scenario can't happen, as /etc/shadow would still not be readable by a non-root user.

Comment: the `#` was intended to demonstrate that the root user ran the command

Comment: Ah, ok - yes, I guess there's plenty of scenarios like this, that depend on the assumption that /root is private to the root user, and the permissions aren't checked. I would classify it as 'contrived'.

Answer (score 0):

If `~root` were writeable, any user could add their SSH key to `~root/.ssh/authorized_keys`, and then have root access simply via `ssh root@some-host`.

If `~root` is "merely" readable, you still have the `root` user's `.bash_history` file accessible, which could contain passwords or other credentials entered on the command line. Or accidentally entered or pasted into a command prompt.

Sure, you're not supposed to pass secure data on the command line, but that warning is generally treated as low-risk because it's racy to catch it in-flight, and other users shouldn't be able to read your environment variables anyway. If you have access to `root`'s `.bash_history` file, you have access to any sensitive data `root` may ever have entered that way, accidentally or not.

Sure, there are mitigations for these issues, like not permitting `root` to login to SSH, even with key auth. Or disabling shell history. Or being studious about cleaning it up. But these are *mitigations*; they're layers in the security onion.

Having `~root` be 0700 is another layer in that security onion. If you don't want to cry, don't peel the onion any more than you have to.

Comment: Thanks fro the reply, but ~root isn't writable in this scenario, and .bash_history has 500 perms (on Centos at least). Nice quote about the onion though!